# Proving a limit exists

Tags: real-analysis

Supposing that a function $g(x)$ is differentiable on the interval $(0,1]$, and $g'(x)$ is bounded on $(0,1]$: show that the limit of $g(1/n)$, as $n$ goes to infinity, exists.

My initial guess was to turn $1/n$ into a point $x$ in $(0,1]$ and change the limit to be ‘as $x$ goes to $0$’, and then work off the definition of differentiation ($g'(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{g(x) - g(0)}{x - 0}$), but I'm doubting myself on that. Any help and guidance would be very appreciated!

Comment: You may not write $g(0)$ as you do not even know whether $g$ is defined at $0$.

Comment: I now realize that! I was desperately looking for something to work with, and in my haste overlooked that obvious fact.

Answer (score 1):

We show that the sequence $(g(1/n))$ is a Cauchy sequence, and therefore converges.

Let $B$ be an upper bound on $|g'(x)|$. By the Mean Value Theorem, we have
$$\left|g(1/n)-g(1/m)\right|\le \left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right|B.$$

For any $\epsilon \gt 0$, we can therefore find an $N$ such that if $m, n \gt N$, then $|g(1/n)-g(1/m)|\lt \epsilon$. For example, we can take $N=\left\lceil \frac{B+1}{\epsilon}\right\rceil$.

Comment: I needed some time to digest this response, but thank you! This makes sense. Since g' is bounded, you can find some upper bound such that the upper bound is greater than any g'. How did I not catch that?

Comment: You are welcome. We need to work with $|g'|$. Cauchy sequences are a natural, since we have **internal** information about the sequence, i.e. we are not told the limit. For the limit, we could use integration, but it is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M = \sup_{x \in (0, 1]} \{|g'(x)|\}$.  Then by the mean value theorem, for all distinct $x, y \in (0, 1]$, we have:
$$\frac{|g(x) - g(y)|}{|x - y|} \leq M.$$

To show that the limit exists, we want to show that $\{g(1/n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.  For fixed $\varepsilon$, let $N = M / \varepsilon$.  Then we have, for $n, m > N$:
\begin{align*}
|g(1/n) - g(1/m)| &= \frac{|g(1/n) - g(1/m)|}{|1/n - 1/m|} (|1/n - 1/m|)\\
&\leq M|1/n - 1/m|\\
& < \frac{M}{N}\\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your response as well! I appreciate it! I was so caught up with rules of differentiation that I forgot about Cauchy sequences.

Comment: In the line with equality, shouldn't it be (on RHS) $\frac{|g(\frac{1}{n})-g(\frac{1}{m})|}{|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|} \cdot |\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|$?

Comment: Whoops!  Yes, you are right.  Fixed it :)